# R convert list with multiple string lengths to data frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list:

```
l1<-list(A=1:10, B=100:120, C=300:310, D=400:430)
```

How do I convert it to dataframe with 2 columns:

```
    C1 C2 
R1  1  A 
R2  2  A 
...
R10 10 A
R11  100  B
R12  101  B
....
R73  429  D
R73  430  D
```

I tried:

```
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(l1), nrow=length(l1), byrow=T))
```

But I'm getting an error because the vectors in my list have multiple lengths. Also my actual list consist of Dates and not just integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `stack`:

```
stack(l1)

> head(stack(l1))
  values ind
1      1   A
2      2   A
3      3   A
4      4   A
5      5   A
6      6   A
> tail(stack(l1))
   values ind
68    425   D
69    426   D
70    427   D
71    428   D
72    429   D
73    430   D
```

***Update***

`stack` won't work with dates. If you have actual date objects, you can do:

```
data.frame(ind = rep(names(l1), lengths(l1)), 
           val = as.Date(unlist(l1), origin = "1970-01-01"))
```

or

```
data.frame(ind = rep(names(l1), lengths(l1)), val = do.call(c, l1))
```

Sample data:

```
l1<-list(A=Sys.Date()+(1:10), 
         B=Sys.Date()+(100:120), 
         C=Sys.Date()+(300:310), 
         D=Sys.Date()+(400:430))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one method: Similar to #Duck answer using `Map` and `do.call`

```
tmp <- Map(data.frame,N = l1,L = names(l1))
out <- do.call(rbind,tmp)
rownames(out) <- NULL

> tail(out)
     N L
68 425 D
69 426 D
70 427 D
71 428 D
72 429 D
73 430 D
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a long solution, but using `mapply()` and `do.call()` you can reach the expected result. First, you can extract the names of the list as well as the number of elements. Then, using `mapply()` you can create a list for the first column in your desired result. After that you combine `mapply()`, `do.call()`, `rbind()` and `cbind()` to end up with `df`. Here the code:

```
#Code
#names
v1 <- names(l1)
#length
v2 <- unlist(lapply(l1, length))
#Create values
l2 <- mapply(function(x,y) rep(x,y),v1,v2)
#Bind
df <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,mapply(cbind,l2,l1)))
df$V2 <- as.numeric(df$V2)
```

Output (some rows):

```
head(df,15)
   V1 V2
1   A  1
2   A 24
3   A 25
4   A 37
5   A 69
6   A 70
7   A 71
8   A 72
9   A 73
10  A  2
11  B  3
12  B  4
13  B  5
14  B  6
15  B  7
```

Comment: Sorry, but this created new values which I did not have in my list (24,25,37...) and put the values from A (3,4,5,6,7) under B.